# CLI to create Google OAuth 2.0 project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

Is there any command line interface to create Google OAuth 2.0 project?
To integrate the log in with Google, we need to register the project by clicking Configure A Project button and then create a new project.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Is there any CLI to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/).

More specifically, you're looking for the command: [`gcloud projects create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create).

You may also want to read about [creating and managing Google Cloud Projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects), since you have limited quota for creating projects. You may also be interested in Google Cloud's [Resource Hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy).

But, most importantly, you may not need a project each time you want to have a new OAuth 2.0 client. Each project can have multiple OAuth 2.0 client IDs/credentials,you just need to fill the settings and [create your client credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#creating_your_client_credentials).